# DataGrid not allowing to edit item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem in Wpf `DataGrid. I am adding values in datagrid's first column called`Model Name`. below I am also giving my code to show the problem.

So my problem is first column will show the values from database and the other columns can be writeable. All the values will save in some database table. when I use `datagrid.Items.Add(data);` then it gives the values in first column, works fine but if I start writing in other columns it gives error

> "Edititem is not allowed".

Here is my code in WPF

```
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Name="DeliveryGrid" IsReadOnly="False"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
                  Margin="0,85,0,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Height="235"
                  Width="462">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Width="90" Binding="{Binding ModelName}" x:Name="ModelName" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Engine No" Width="90" x:Name="EngineNo" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Chasis No" Width="90" x:Name="ChasisNo" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Authority No" Width="90" x:Name="AuthorityNo" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" x:Name="Price" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Here Is my Code in C#

```
public class BikesOrderObjects
    {
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        public string BEngineNo { get; set; }
        public string BChasisNo { get; set; }
        public string BAuthorityNo { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
    }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            LoadDeliveryData();

        }

        private void LoadDeliveryData()
        {
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            var BikesOrderData = conn.TblBikesOrdersDetails
                .Where(TblBikesOrdersDetail => TblBikesOrdersDetail.BOId == 1)
                            .Select(TblBikesOrdersDetail => new
                            {
                                qty = TblBikesOrdersDetail.BQty,
                                ModelID = TblBikesOrdersDetail.ModelId,
                                ModelName = TblBikesOrdersDetail.TblBikeModel.ModelName
                            });
            foreach (var item in BikesOrderData)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.qty; i++)
                {
                    var data = new BikesOrderObjects { ModelName = item.ModelName };
                    DeliveryGrid.Items.Add(data);
                }


            }


        }
```

Comment: can you share BikesOrderObjects code?

Comment: @nit Thanks!, i have provide now

Comment: You are binding the first column oneway, is there a reason you are not binding the other columns?

Answer (score 2):

You `should not update the Items` directly of your `DataGrid` but rather set the `ItemsSource` to the collection that implements `IEditableCollectionView` interface in order to allow the editing. This interface has function `EditItems()` which let the editing happen.

So in order solve this problem. Create the `ObservableCollection<BikesOrderObjects>` property say MyBikesOrders in your window and bind the `DataGrid ItemsSource` to it like

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBikesOrders}"/>
```

assuming you have set the `DataContext` of your window to itself.

In your constructor you can initialize this collection by newing it and in `LoadDeliveryData` method add the object to this collection.

Comment: That's right. Also, make sure you do not use `LoadingRow` event for this purpose. After applying @nit's suggestion, remove the use of `LoadingRow`.

Comment: Thanks @nit, i am new to wpf c#, can you please give a short example so that i feel little easy to understand.Thanks!

Comment: as explained in answer, just create the property of type observablecollection in codebehind and bind it to the Datagrid. And update this property instead of Items directly.. this will update your DataGrid and will allow editing

Answer (score 1):

i got solution here is my code

```
     private void LoadDeliveryData()
        {
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            var BikesOrderData = conn.TblBikesOrdersDetails
                .Where(TblBikesOrdersDetail => TblBikesOrdersDetail.BOId == 1)
                            .Select(TblBikesOrdersDetail => new
                            {
                                qty = TblBikesOrdersDetail.BQty,
                                ModelID = TblBikesOrdersDetail.ModelId,
                                ModelName = TblBikesOrdersDetail.TblBikeModel.ModelName
                            });
            List<BikesOrderObjects> data = new List<BikesOrderObjects>();
            foreach (var item in BikesOrderData)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < item.qty; i++)
                {
                    BikesOrderObjects datae = new BikesOrderObjects();
                    datae.ModelName = item.ModelName;
                    data.Add(datae);
                }

            }

            DeliveryGrid.ItemsSource = data;

        }
```