# When clicking on datagrid row it throws me exception - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Whenever I try to double click my datagrid row to edit it, I throws me a few exceptions which doesn't say anything to me. Hovever if I set the whole datagrid to IsReadOnly to true, I want have the problem, but I need the second and third columns editable.

XAML

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="clientList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="225" Margin="11,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="349" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB9B9B9" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF8B8B8B" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#66240000" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CC240000" Offset="0.65"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Company" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Company}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130" Header="Name, Surname" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns> 
    </DataGrid>
```

C#

```
clientList.Items.Add(new DataClients { Id = 1, Company = "My Company", Name = "Jane Roe"});
```

Exceptions

```
Exception:Thrown: "'EditItem' is not allowed for this view."(System.InvalidOperationException)

Exception:Thrown: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." (System.FormatException)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952456/datagrid-not-allowing-to-edit-item)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ObservableCollection<DataClients>()` as source for your Datagrid and not add the items directly to your `DataGrid`. To do this, you create a property `ObservableCollection<DataClients> Data` and use it as the `ItemsSource` in your `DataGrid`like this `ItemsSource="{Binding MyBikesOrders}"`. You can then add the items to the `ObservableCollection`, update the `DataGrid` and you should be able to edit the entries directly in it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952456/datagrid-not-allowing-to-edit-item)'s a very similar question to yours.